# Fecha en java script llega con un dia menos

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando un sistema donde ingreso fechas, pero mi problema es al validar ya que si ingreso una fecha en un `<input type="date">`  me llega con un dia anteior. Ejemplo, si ingreso la fecha de hoy a js me llega con la fecha de ayer pero a la base de datos si llega con la fecha que indique osea la de hoy no entiendo porque.

MI codigo es el siguiente.

```
function addReunion() {

    var f = new Date();

    try {
        nmreu = document.getElementById('txtevento').value;
        dteinicio = document.getElementById('dateinicio').value;
        dtefin = document.getElementById('datefin').value;
        timeinicio = document.getElementById('timeinicio').value;
        timefin = document.getElementById('timefin').value;

        // f.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        dti = new Date(dteinicio);
        dtf = new Date(dtefin);

        console.log('actual ', f);
        console.log('inicio ', dti);

        $('#dtinvalid').addClass('alert alert-danger');


        if (dteinicio === null || dteinicio === '') {
            $('#dtinvalid').text('Seleccione una fecha de inicio');
        } else if (dti < f) {
            $('#dtinvalid').text('Fecha de inicio invalida');
        } else if (dtefin === null || dtefin === '') {
            $('#dtinvalid').text('Seleccione una fecha final');
        } else if (dtf < f || dtf < dti) {
            $('#dtinvalid').text('Fecha final invalida');
        } else if (timeinicio === null || timeinicio === '') {
            $('#dtinvalid').text('Hora de inicio invalida');
        } else if (timefin === null || timefin === '') {
            $('#dtinvalid').text('Hora final invalida');
        } else {
            window.location = `meetings?accion=Asignar&namereunion=${nmreu}&dteinicio=${dteinicio}&dtefin=${dtefin}&timeinicio=${timeinicio}&timefin=${timefin}`;
        }

    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error en addreunion en js');
    }
}
```

Comment: Deberías editar tu código agregando los textos html, para así poderte ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que estas validando fechas si son menores podrias hacer esto para que te sume un dia en la fecha que recibe de los input te aseguro que servira.

```
 dti.setDate(dti.getDate() + 1);
```

y a las horas del dia actual deberias dejarlas en 0 dejala sin comentariar, esto hazlo con la fecha final la actual e inicial. Yo lo hecho asi y me funciona incluso para ver si son iguales, ya que no estas validando horas.

```
 f.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
 dti.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: genial me funciono super bien, facil y codigo mas corto gracias solucionaste mi problema.

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que sumarle 1, ya que las fechas empiezan en 0 y no en 1.

ej.

```
// Obtenemos la fecha del dia e invertimos los valores para mostrarlos
n =  new Date();
y = n.getFullYear();
m = n.getMonth() + 1;
d = n.getDate();
if(m <= 9){
    m = "0"+m;
}
// lo ordenamos y guardamos en la variable fechaHoy
var fechaHoy = `${y}-${m}-${d}`;

//Aplica la fecha de hoy en el campo de fecha del formulario
document.getElementById("fechaMovimiento").value = fechaHoy;
//Invertimos el orden de la fecha para pasarlo al header
var fechaHeader = `${d}-${m}-${y}`;
```

Si te fijas, en m (mes) estoy sumando el 1 que falta. también puedes usar el operador de auto incremento.

Comment: ¿Sumarle un 1 al mes hace que la fecha de ayer se convierta en fecha de hoy?. Esto no es ni de lejos una respuesta a la pregunta formulada. Por favor revisa tu respuesta porque no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta. El problema que el OP tiene está más relacionado (posiblemente) con la zona horaria del sistema con respecto a lo que almacena en la BD.

Comment: en realidad se convertirian en el mes siguiente @MauricioContreras.. o no?

Comment: @Mauricio La solucion de Mauricio Contreras no me funciono porque al validar estaria validando un String no un formarto de fecha entonces no tiene sentido.